# Clips in Premiere Pro are correct in source window but cropped when copied into timeline

Tags: editing, premiere-pro

I tried to attach two images to show the difference but it doesn't seem possible, so this is just the cropped version. I shot some exteriors with exactly the same settings as my previous footage, and in the source window they're fine but as soon as I import them into the assembly (different timeline) they're cropped. I've tried adjusting the percentage and all other things that were obvious to me (not a pro). I really need this help, if anybody can give it, please. [image]